# How does a latent variable's communality value (R-squared) afect the interpretation of a latent basis model?

Tags: panel-data, factor-analysis, growth-model, mplus

I am running a latent basis model with 5 time points.
The model has 5 measures of 5 items that make a factor.
I ran the model with the folloing code(Mplus) ;

```
  i s | AE1@0 AE2* AE3* AE4* AE5@1;
```

the unstandardized slope estimates are;
[image: unstandardized slope estimate]

here, AE3 shows a drop but it is unsignificant, I guess due to
its large standardized error. Also, when I look at the R-square
values for the respeated measure, it looks like this.
[image]

This seems very odd since the data has been tested for invariance
(partial strong invariance) and makes me if I am able to think that
the slope for AE3 is reliable or not.
It would be great if someone can provide me with some insite.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: R-square is prolly the worst performance metric one can use, at least imo. Why not do a PCA and examine the communalities? Looking at the slope estimates, the *999*s for AE5 raise questions about linear combinations, don't you think? In terms of rel importance, AE4 has the largest Est/SE value suggesting it's the dominant feature.

Comment: AE5 is a fixed loading and therefore has no standard error or z test statistic. The "999" simply indicates "n/a".

Comment: The R-square can be useful as one indicator of the fit of a growth model. If the R-square is low this means that the growth factors do not account for much variability in the observed scores and/or that a growth model may not be the best way to represent the data at all. For example, there may be large situation-specific (time-specific) variations rather than a clear growth or decline pattern. In that case, a latent state-trait-model may be more suitable than a growth model.

Comment: Thank you both for the insightful comments. I believe in summary, R-square is not so indicative relative to the main interpretation of the model but is something to keep in mind. I would like to see what is happening at AE3 (academic self-efficacy at time 3) so I would look for sources of why or what caused the distinct variability. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter estimates seem rather unstable (the slope factor loadings have high standard errors as you pointed out). I wonder whether there is a clear change pattern in the data at all. What does AE stand for (what type of construct is it?)? How large was the sample and did you expect changes?

Have you looked at a plot of the individual growth curves? Perhaps a lot of individuals showed fluctuations (ups and downs, "state variability") but did not follow a clear general growth/decline trajectory. This could explain why your slope factor with free loadings is rather unstable.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I am trying hard to get the plots of output files generated by Mplus as my main PC is a Mac. I have tried to import the gh5 (or out) files on a Windows PC but it does not give me the option of generating individual trajectories. I tried the following;
1) open the gh5 (or .out) file in a Windows PC and use the Plot.
2) install shiny in R and use the visualization app
Both only give me the options of histogram, scatter plot, estimated means,
and latent variable distribution plots. Any suggestions?

Comment: AE stands for academic self-efficacy and the numbers show the wave. The fluctuation and unstableness are something that I assumed and the character of the unstableness (large variability in group and the rapid ups and downs) is something that I usually see as a classroom teacher of this age group.

Comment: How about using the free Mplus demo version for Windows and generating the graphs within the Windows version? You have only 5 variables in your model so the demo version should be sufficient.

Comment: If there are no more long-lasting/permanent changes in academic self-efficacy over the course of your study (but only situation-specific fluctuations), a latent state-trait model may be a better fit (a slope/growth/change factor may not be needed). If you have multiple indicators (e.g., items or subscales) of AE you could run an LST model with multiple indicators at each wave.